# BadMethodExcption in Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I created a controller in Laravel, but when I call a method on the Controller it shows the following error:

> BadMethodCallException
>       Method [Register] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\UserController].

Controller Code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

public function Index()
{
        echo "hello";
}

public function Register()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = "Aisha";
    $user->email = "aishaemail@yahoo.com";
    $user->password = "TestPass";
    $user->remember_token = str_random(16);
    $user->save();
}
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/user/register','UserController@Register');
```

Comment: Please show the route and controller.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: Thanks its working

Answer (score -2):

```
public function Register()
{
    $user = new User; // Create a new User collection..
    $user->name = "Aisha";
    $user->email = "aishaemail@yahoo.com";
    $user->password = "TestPass";
    $user->remember_token = str_random(16);
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: So, what did you change? You should elaborate your answer.